# How to add checkbox to existing paypal code?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, paypal

i have gotten some javascript code of paypal that can be put onto a website for donations. This code didnt have a checkbox for terms and conditions on it so i have tried to add my own.
The problem is i cant lock the submit button or have it display the error code that i have created if the box is unchecked.
Any suggestions?

ORIGINAL CODE FROM PAYPAL:

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center"><label for="description">Your Name/In Game Name/Nickname </label><input type="text" name="descriptionInput" id="description" maxlength="127" value=""></div>
      <p id="descriptionError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter a description</p>
    <div style="text-align: center"><label for="amount">Donation Amount </label><input name="amountInput" type="number" id="amount" value="" ><span> GBP</span></div>
      <p id="priceLabelError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter a price</p>
    <div id="invoiceidDiv" style="text-align: center; display: none;"><label for="invoiceid">Leave a note: </label><input name="invoiceid" maxlength="127" type="text" id="invoiceid" value="" ></div>
      <p id="invoiceidError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter an Invoice ID</p>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0.625rem;" id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
  function initPayPalButton() {
    var description = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #description');
    var amount = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #amount');
    var descriptionError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #descriptionError');
    var priceError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #priceLabelError');
    var invoiceid = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceid');
    var invoiceidError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidError');
    var invoiceidDiv = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidDiv');

    var elArr = [description, amount];

    if (invoiceidDiv.firstChild.innerHTML.length > 1) {
      invoiceidDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    var purchase_units = [];
    purchase_units[0] = {};
    purchase_units[0].amount = {};

    function validate(event) {
      return event.value.length > 0;
    }

    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'paypal',
        layout: 'vertical',
        
      },

      onInit: function (data, actions) {
        actions.disable();

        if(invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          elArr.push(invoiceid);
        }

        elArr.forEach(function (item) {
          item.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            var result = elArr.every(validate);
            if (result) {
              actions.enable();
            } else {
              actions.disable();
            }
          });
        });
      },

      onClick: function () {
        if (description.value.length < 1) {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (amount.value.length < 1) {
          priceError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          priceError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (invoiceid.value.length < 1 && invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        purchase_units[0].description = description.value;
        purchase_units[0].amount.value = amount.value;

        if(invoiceid.value !== '') {
          purchase_units[0].invoice_id = invoiceid.value;
        }
      },

      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: purchase_units,
        });
      },

      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
      },

      onError: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
  initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

i then added this to the original code:

```
<div id="acceptdiv" style="text-align: center; "><input  type="checkbox" id="acceptid" value="checked" onClick="function ()"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions above</div>
      <p id="acceptError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please accept the terms and conditions </p>


  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
  function initPayPalButton() {

    var acceptdiv = document.getElementById("acceptid");
    var acceptError = document.getElementById("acceptError");


      onClick: function () {

        if (checkBox.checked === true){
            acceptError.style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
            acceptError.style.visibility = "visible";
```

i have the checkbox working but cant get the error message to show or lock the button

Comment: this doesn't look anything like regular paypal code. It even contains `alert()`, where did you get this? Paypal donations are either by link (to a paypal page) or through iframe (loading a paypal page) because your site should _never_ see what people fill in.

Comment: It is normal PayPal JS SDK button code.  Where is 'checkBox' defined in your second code block, however?